# Button to Open a LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

I need to create new button called ‘XYZ’ to be accessible on Opportunity record at the top of the page layout (Standard page) that will open a pop window with my LWC. How can I do this the most simplest way. One Issue is that my components are build in LWC and I can not put the standard pages.

The Scenario is below: 
When Users click on the XYZ button from the Opportunity a new window should open within the Opportunity Record with the XYZ LWC fields.

Any Help Is Appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For now, you can use an Aura Component to wrap your LWC component, then make that Aura Component a Quick Action. Doing this will allow you to add it to the page as a button in the upper-right menu for a record.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant [LWC recipes Example.](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/aura/auraEmbeddedLWC/auraEmbeddedLWC.cmp)

You can also just use `force:hasRecordId` and `force:lightningQuickAction` tag and use the record id from the parent aura component to pass it to a child LWC component. This will allow it to be used as a quick action.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Modal' LWC base component was recently introduced.

Write the pop up page as a Modal component, then on the page that launches it, you import the Modal component and open it from a button click handler.

Follow the documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation

*(This content was originally posted on salesforce.stackexchange.com)*